# How do I add address of struct to binary linker output

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, bare-metal

This might seem a strange question, but I'm generating a binary file and need to put some data in the header.

I'm using gcc and a fairly standard Cortex M4 bare-bones linker script.

Instead of putting the ISR vector first in the binary, I'm putting my own header. The binary will be copied to a pre-determined memory location (0x20008000, to which it has been linked) and run from there.

my startup.s contains this:

```
.section  .isr_vector,"a",%progbits
.type  g_pfnVectors, %object
.size  g_pfnVectors, .-g_pfnVectors    

g_pfnVectors:
  .word 0xDADAC0DE       /* magic number */
  .word .isr_vector      /* link base address */
  .word Reset_Handler    /* code entry point */
  .word _end             /* stack start */
  .word _estack          /* stack end */
  .word ProgramVector    /* pointer to shared memory block */
```

This all works fine, with the exception of ProgramVector. I define it in my main.c as follows:

```
 typedef struct {
     uint8_t checksum;
     int16_t* audio_input;
     int16_t* audio_output;
...
   } SharedMemory;

  SharedMemory ProgramVector;
```

I would expect the binary to include the address to ProgramVector. If I compare the output to what I see in the linker map file, everything matches (Reset_Handler, _end, _estack) but not ProgramVector.

My binary file `app.bin` :

```
00000000  de c0 da da 00 80 00 20  0d 9a 00 20 d8 ce 00 20  |....... ... ... |
00000010  00 c0 01 20 60 ce 00 20  60 ce 00 20 4f 57 4c 20  |... `.. `.. OWL |
00000020  50 72 6f 67 72 61 6d 00  10 b5 05 4c 23 78 33 b9  |Program....L#x3.|
```

From which we can determine that `ProgramVector` is 0x2000ce60, while my map files says:

```
                0x2001c000                _estack = 0x2001c000
...
     .bss           0x2000ae28       0x38 Build/main.o
                    0x2000ae28                ProgramVector
...
                0x2000ced8                PROVIDE (_end, .)
```

Now you might say that ProgramVector is not a pointer, which is true enough. But I would expect the linker to output the address where it is placed. If I make it a `SharedMemory*` pointer, the output has the correct address of the pointer. The problem is I need the address of the struct, and I need it before the program has initialised.

I have tried this with a variety of compiler and linker flags, to no avail. Current compilation looks like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wl,--gc-sections -TSource/flash.ld -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -o Build/app.elf Build/sta./Build/libnosys_gnu.o -lm
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary Build/solo.elf Build/solo.bin
```

I'm probably missing something obvious but going mad trying to figure out what. Any help, pointers or advice appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware that you can change the base-address of the vector table in `NVIC->VTOR`? So you can use a normal verctor table and just remap in _startup. However, I have to guess, as the question is not quite clear. If you intend to call the binary another way, you will need a bootloader Which calls the actual program code. That would reside in a different Flash secotr, so it would not be affected by updating the regular firmware. It would also set `VTOR` to the new entry (you need that vector table, as some vectors cannot be disabled (e.g. hardfault) and do need a valid vector.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, and apologies for being short on background information - I didn't want to turn the question into a book! I do have a bootloader and firmware, with a vector table, in a separate flash sector. That part also uses separate RAM; it loads and runs the binary fine. I have up to now been keeping the ProgramVector data in NVRAM accessed from both programs: interrupts running from one, main thread from the other. I'd like to put it instead inside the dynamically loaded program, partly for performance and convenience, partly to make it easier to set up the MPU.

Comment: Sound overcomplicated to me, but hey, that's your project (I currently have a similar on M4 and with heavy MPU usage). But I just use the vector relocation; the bootloader is inactive once it passes control.

Comment: It is complicated, but it's the only way I can see which allows me to maintain a USB connection and audio processing while dynamically loading and running DSP code.

Comment: Hmm.. So you do not need to change interrupt vectors, just dynamically load/unload DSP functions? I would expect the Flash of typical Cortex-M3 to be large enough to store all at once; otherwise I would prefer a Cortex-A5 or A7 which kost not much more. Btw: for DSP the M4 might be better suited. Not only because of its SIMD instructions (might be worthless for Audio with > 16 bit fractional), but for its FPU, too.

Comment: This is on an STM32F4 Cortex M4, and yes I love the FPU. The DSP code is not known in advance, hence the dynamic loading. About inserting the address of ProgramVector: the actual number in the binary, 0x2000ce60 in this case, doesn't correspond with anything at all in the map file. Is that not a bit weird?

Comment: Ok, so the M3 liker script was missleading. Hmm.. if that is really M3, you should adopt it, as the CCM in the F4 is really a great help (but not for code or DMA!). I'm currently more curious about the announced F7. For the details: sorry, I'm just done working on my own project for today and I'm absolutely not up to some more voluntary programming right now.

Comment: oops, yes, that should read 'standard Cortex M4 link script' - fixed, thanks!

Comment: Comete to "Cortex-M4F" (like **F**PU) and I'll be happy ;-)